# regex: symbols can't repeat next to eachother

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make regex that picks all words that are a-z and with or without the symbol '.

1. the word needs to be at least 2 characters
2. cant start with the ' symbol
3. two ' symbols can't be next to each other
4. and "two character" words can't end with the ' symbol

I have being working for hours on that regex and i can't make it work:

```
/\b[a-z]([a-z(\')](?!\1))+\b/
```

it does not work and i don't know why! (the two ' symbols next to each other)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([a-z](?:[a-z]|'(?!'))+[a-z']|[a-z]{2})
```

[Live @ RegExPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5Ba-z%5D%28?%3a%5Ba-z%5D%7C%27%28?!%27%29%29%2b%5Ba-z%27%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%7B2%7D%29&input=az%27%0Aa%27dfgasdf%27%0Aasfdharehgafd%27%0Agafdhafdgjk%27afdg%27%0Aa%27%0A%27a%0Aa%27a%0Aaaa%27aaaaa%27)

You probably will not need to use `\b` as regex is greedy and will consume all words as a whole.
This version can't be tested with RegexPal (does not recognize the lookbehind) but has custom word borders:

```
(?<![a-z'])([a-z](?:[a-z]|'(?!'))+[a-z']|[a-z]{2})(?![a-z'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (disclaimer: untested)

```
/\b(?![a-z]{2}'\b)[a-z]((?!'')['a-z])+\b/
```

Yours does not because you are attempting to nest a parenthesized expression inside a character class. That only adds `(` and `)` to the class, it will not set the value of your next `\1` code.

(Edit) Added the constraint on `aa'`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming words are delimited by spaces:

```
(?:^|\s)((?:[a-z]{2})|(?:[a-z](?!.*'')[a-z']{2,}))(?:$|\s)
```

In action in a perl script:

```
my $re = qr/(?:^|\s)((?:[a-z]{2})|(?:[a-z](?!.*'')[a-z']{2,}))(?:$|\s)/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK: $_" : "KO: $_");
}
__DATA__
ab
abc
a'
ab''
abc'
a''b
:!ù
```

**output:**

```
OK: ab
OK: abc
KO: a'
OK: ab''
OK: abc'
KO: a''b
KO: :!ù
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\b((?:[a-z]{2})|(?:[a-z](?!.*'')[a-z']{2,}))\b)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]{2}                 any character of: 'a' to 'z' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''                       '\'\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z']{2,}               any character of: 'a' to 'z', ''' (at
                               least 2 times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```